# How should I mock out a single method inside an object I'm trying to test?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a problem with a class that I am testing where in almost every method I want to test, one of the first things each method does is call this one specific method. This method that is called once by all of these other methods takes a long time to execute. I don't want to have to wait for this every time I run my tests, it really is just a huge waste of time.

I attempted to @Spy the method using Mocktio, but I ran into problems because the really long method doesn't return anything. Can someone suggest a good way to mock out a single method inside a class I am trying to test?

---

Example:

```
public class myClass {

    public void methodOne() {
        reallyLongMethod();
        // More code
    }

    public void methodTwo() {
        reallyLongMethod();
        // More code
    }

    .
    .
    .

    public void methodN() {
        reallyLongMethod();
        // More code
    }

    public void reallyLongMethod() {

    }
}
```

This is the class I am trying to test. I want to test all of the 'methodX()' methods. I don't want to run reallyLongMethod everysingle time however.

So, is there a way to use Mockito 'Spy' to stub out reallyLongMethod()? Even though it doesn'treturn anything?

Comment: Have you tried `doNothing().when(spy).reallyLongMethod()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Spy with `doNothing()`, but make sure you use the spy during the test. Mockito spies copy the original, instead of delegating to it.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourTest {
  // Option 1:
  // @Spy MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

  // Option 2 (see @Before method)
  MyClass myClass;

  @Before public void ignoreReallyLongMethod() {
    myClass = spy(new MyClass());  // discard original
    doNothing().when(myClass).reallyLongMethod();
  }

  @Test public void methodOneWorks() {
    myClass.methodOne();  // you're using the spy here
    assertEquals(42, myClass.getFoo());
  }
}
```

Though this does evoke a code smell, *don't mock or stub the class under test*, as long as you're careful to test the method behavior (`methodOne`) and not the stubbed behavior (`reallyLongMethod`) you'll be good to go. If you do want to test `reallyLongMethod` you'll want to use a different object instance or else you'll "test" the `doNothing()` call alone. Do bear in mind that if `reallyLongMethod` and your other methods have any *negative interactions*, these tests won't tell you about that.

---

By the way, you can also do the equivalent without using Mockito, which may make a little clearer what you are or aren't doing with your mocks:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class YourTest {
  MyClass myClass;

  @Before public void createMyClass() {
    myClass = new MyClass() {  // create an anonymous inner class
      @Override public void reallyLongMethod() {}  // that does nothing here
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this I just get following error: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();

Comment: Ah, it works with the more explicit example, but when I attempt to just use the annotation it doesn't work for some reason. Thank you though.

Comment: If you use the annotation, make sure you add the `@RunWith` up top, as that's the part that initializes `@Mock` and `@Spy` fields. Glad this solved your problem overall!